# Coq Reals and Ssreflect GRings

Tags: coq, real-number, ssreflect

I'd like to use ssreflect's lemmas on the Reals defined in `Coq.Reals.Raxioms`.
How do I do that?

For example, I'd like to be able to use the `add`, `mul`, etc. operations defined for `ssralg.GRing.Ring` directly on variables of type `Rdefintions.R` and apply the `Num.real_closed_axiom` directly on Coq reals.

Is it necessary to prove all the structures from eqType, choice, zmodule, etc, up to the ClosedReals?  If so, someone must have done so before, but I have not been able to find it.  Is there some other development I can use?

If not so, what is the right way to do it via axioms? Does one have to add additional coercions and `Canonical` structure statements.

Comment: I haven't looked at it closely, but [math-comp/analysis](https://github.com/math-comp/analysis) might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anton's response is correct, this issue was discussed in a recent MathComp meeting, and an "official" experimental bindings to Coq's reals can be found at https://github.com/math-comp/analysis/blob/master/Rstruct.v

Note that the above library is still in heavy development, I suggest you directly discuss with the developers for more information.

Comment: Thanks. Are there longer term plans for Coquelicot and ssreflect to integrate more closely?

Comment: I'm afraid I am not the right person to answer that question.